# Called methods (with the same name) from different parent class, but results appear code only runs one of them

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I built three kinds of dices, then use a cup to wrap it. Cup inherits two classes (which inherit the same base class). In cup, I called three roll methods from the two parent classes and the base class.

When I run cup.roll, I should get three numbers, the first one should range from 1-6, second 1-10, third 1-20. But I ran many times, and the results show all the three numbers range from 1-10, which means only the roll method only derives from the one of the parent class.

Why did this happen? And how to solve this issue? I'm just starting with Python.

### Update

The problem above is solved by change the structure of Cup, but I have got a new issue.

Now, the code works fine until the last part when I output the result, there should be three list returned from three dices, but the last two are empty, where, when roll and sum, they aren't empty. Very weird.

Output:

```
# >>> c = cup(2,3,4)
# 2 3 4
# >>> c.roll()
# (when print out roll in dices)
# [5, 2]
# [2, 6, 2]
# [6, 6, 2, 5]
# (but, when print out roll in cup, two become empty)
# [5, 2] [] []
# 36
```

Code:

```
class SixSidedDie:
    sides = 6
    valueLst = []
    sumVal = int()

    def __init__(self, nOfDie):
        self.nOfDie = nOfDie

    def roll(self):
        import random
        self.valueLst = []
        for i in range(1, self.nOfDie+1):
            self.valueLst.append(random.randint(1,self.sides))
        print(self.valueLst)
        return self.valueLst

    def sum(self):
        self.sumVal = 0
        for i in self.valueLst:
            self.sumVal += i
        return self.sumVal

    def getFaceValue(self):
        return self.valueLst

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SixSidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue)



class TenSidedDie(SixSidedDie):
    sides = 10          
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TenSidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue) 



class TwentySidedDie(SixSidedDie):

    sides = 20
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TwentySidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue) 





class cup():   

    sixSDLst = []
    tenSDLst = []
    twentySDLst = []

    def __init__(self, nOfSixSdDie = 1, nOfTenSdDie = 1, nOfTwentySdDie = 1):
        self.sixSdDie = SixSidedDie(nOfSixSdDie)
        self.tenSdDie = TenSidedDie(nOfTenSdDie)
        self.twentySdDie = TwentySidedDie(nOfTwentySdDie)
        print(nOfSixSdDie, nOfTenSdDie, nOfTwentySdDie)

    def roll(self):
        self.sixSDLst = self.sixSdDie.roll()
        self.tenSDlst = self.tenSdDie.roll()
        self.twentySDlst= self.twentySdDie.roll()
        print(self.sixSDLst,self.tenSDLst,self.twentySDLst)
        return self.sixSdDie.sum() + self.tenSdDie.sum() + self.twentySdDie.sum()

    def getSum(self):
        return self.sixSdDie.sum()+ self.tenSdDie.sum() + self.twentySdDie.sum()

    def __repr__(self):
        output = ''
        for i in self.sixSDLst:
            output = output + 'SixSidedDie(' + str(i) +'),'

        for j in self.tenSDLst:
            output = output + 'TenSidedDie(' + str(i) +'),'

        for k in self.twentySDLst[:-1]:
            output = output + 'TwentySidedDie(' + str(i) +'),'
        output = 'Cup(' + output + 'TwentySidedDie(' + str(self.twentySDLst[-1]) +')' + ')'
        return output
```

Comment: This is not at all how inheritance should be used. You shouldn't make a new class just because you want to change the number of faces a dice has. And a cup most certainly isn't a ten-sided die and a twenty-sided die at the same time. In fact it's not a die at all, and so it shouldn't inherit from one.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for your advice. The first three classes are coded as what my hw requires. As for the cup, I guess I made a mistake. Can you please give some hints? What kind of structure should I use for cup?

Comment: A cup should most likely *contain* dice, so you should create `Die` instances and let the `Cup` hold on to them.

Comment: I should compose those into cup instead of inheriting, rewriting it now.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'll read it later. Thank you for letting me know. I'll be careful with it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as others have said, you're using inheritance wrong, but I'm chalk that up to the homework requirements.

in your Dice subclasses try updating the number of sides in the `__init__` method:

```
class TenSidedDie(SixSidedDie):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = 10

    def __repr__(self):
       return 'TenSidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue)
```

Also, when calling roll you don't need to include self.

```
for k in range(1, self.nOfTwentySdDie+1):
            self.fVOfTwentySdDie.append(TwentySidedDie.roll())
```

---

With your updated code:

Commenting out the global initialized lists worked for me.

As a side note, when printing information you want to be able to look at the logs and immediately understand it. I suggest adding the following line to roll roll method: `print('Rolling [{}], count: [{}] values: {}'.format(self.sides, self.nOfDie, self.valueLst))` This will tell you what size of dice you are rolling, how many, and the results of each. No more parsing logs.

---

Since you're only having technical issues and not asking for your homework to be done for you, this is the code that I have that works for me. I did some minor rewrites to make it more manageable for me and added logging:

```
import random

class SixSidedDie:
    sides = 6
    valueLst = []
    sumVal = int()

    def __init__(self, nOfDie):
        print('intializing d6 with [{}] dice'.format(nOfDie))
        self.nOfDie = nOfDie

    def roll(self):
        self.valueLst = []
        for i in range(1, self.nOfDie+1):
            self.valueLst.append(random.randint(1,self.sides))
        print('Rolling {} d{} values: {}'.format(self.nOfDie, self.sides, self.valueLst))
        return self.valueLst

    def sum(self):
        self.sumVal = 0
        for i in self.valueLst:
            self.sumVal += i
        return self.sumVal

    def getFaceValue(self):
        return self.valueLst

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SixSidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue)

class TenSidedDie(SixSidedDie):
    def __init__(self, nOfDie):
        print('intializing d10 with [{}] dice'.format(nOfDie))
        self.nOfDie = nOfDie
        self.sides = 10

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TenSidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue) 

class TwentySidedDie(SixSidedDie):
    def __init__(self, nOfDie):
        print('intializing d20 with [{}] dice'.format(nOfDie))
        self.nOfDie = nOfDie
        self.sides = 20

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'TwentySidedDie({})'.format(self.faceValue) 


class cup():

    def __init__(self, nOfSixSdDie = 1, nOfTenSdDie = 1, nOfTwentySdDie = 1):
        self.sixSdDie = SixSidedDie(nOfSixSdDie)
        self.tenSdDie = TenSidedDie(nOfTenSdDie)
        self.twentySdDie = TwentySidedDie(nOfTwentySdDie)

    def getSum(self):
        return self.sixSdDie.sum()+ self.tenSdDie.sum() + self.twentySdDie.sum()

    def roll(self):
        self.sixSdLst = self.sixSdDie.roll()
        self.tenSdLst = self.tenSdDie.roll()
        self.twentySdLst = self.twentySdDie.roll()
        return self.getSum()

    def __repr__(self):
        output = ''
        print('6 sided : [{}]\n10 sided: [{}]\n20 sided: [{}]'.format(len(self.sixSdLst), len(self.tenSdLst), len(self.twentySdLst)))
        for i in self.sixSdLst:
            output += 'SixSidedDie(' + str(i) +'),'
        output += '\n'

        for j in self.tenSdLst:
            output += 'TenSidedDie(' + str(j) +'),'
        output += '\n'

        for k in self.twentySdLst:
            output += 'TwentySidedDie(' + str(k) +'),'
        result = 'Cup(' + output + ')'
        return result


play_cup = cup(20, 20, 20)

print('ROLL:', play_cup.roll())
print('SUM:', play_cup.getSum())
print(play_cup)
```

Results:

```
intializing d6 with [5] dice
intializing d10 with [5] dice
intializing d20 with [5] dice
Rolling 5 d6 values: [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
Rolling 5 d10 values: [6, 4, 5, 7, 3]
Rolling 5 d20 values: [9, 8, 2, 5, 10]
ROLL: 69
6 sided : [5]
10 sided: [5]
20 sided: [5]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[6, 4, 5, 7, 3]
[9, 8, 2, 5, 10]
Cup(SixSidedDie(1),SixSidedDie(2),SixSidedDie(2),SixSidedDie(2),SixSidedDie(3),
TenSidedDie(6),TenSidedDie(4),TenSidedDie(5),TenSidedDie(7),TenSidedDie(3),
TwentySidedDie(9),TwentySidedDie(8),TwentySidedDie(2),TwentySidedDie(5),TwentySidedDie(10),)
```

Comment: I rewrote cup, it works much better now, but still I got two empty lists from Ten and Twenty sided dices when I print out the result, but when roll and sum, they are not empty.

Comment: I copied your code and had to play with it a bit, but commenting out the empty list initialization in your cup class worked for me.
```
class cup():   

#    sixSDLst = []
#    tenSDLst = []
#    twentySDLst = [] 
...
```

Comment: How are you using cup? like initializing the class? The cup.roll() method will initialize the lists for you.
Right at the bottom I added `play_cup = cup(20, 20, 20)
print('ROLL:', play_cup.roll())
print('SUM:', play_cup.getSum())
print(play_cup)` then ran the whole file.

Comment: I tried what you told me just now, got: AttributeError: 'cup' object has no attribute 'tenSDLst'. I assume sixSDLst is initialized, but not tenSDLst and twenty..so frustrating

Comment: See my edit. I saved all that code into a single file: `cup_rolling.py` and ran it in the bash shell `python cup_rolling.py`. Compare that to how your code.

Comment: Thank you so so so ....much! @sparks  I copied it, let me see what will happen

Comment: It works. You saved my life! I genuinly appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I didn't notice that you were using different variable names for the loops, which is what was causing the printing issue earlier. I updated the code. `str(i)` vs `str(j)` or `str(k)`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because sides are inherited form TenSidedDie which you then pass to each roll as self. Add `print(self.sides)` at the start of your `cup` definition to see it in action. 
From [python class docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance):

```
class DerivedClassName(Base1, Base2, Base3):
   <statement-1>
    .
    .
    .
   <statement-N>
```

> For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search
>   for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first,
>   left-to-right, not searching twice in the same class where there is an
>   overlap in the hierarchy. Thus, if an attribute is not found in
>   DerivedClassName, it is searched for in Base1, then (recursively) in
>   the base classes of Base1, and if it was not found there, it was
>   searched for in Base2, and so on.

you can do something like this to solve after removing the inheritance:

```
 six_die =  SixSidedDie()
 for i in range(1, self.nOfSixSdDie+1):            
     self.fVOfSixSdDie.append(six_die.roll())
```

Comment: I tried, indeed, it prints 10 every time. But how to solve this problem?

Comment: As per @Aran-Fey comment - cup should not be inheriting from die. Instead the cup should call each class whenever a roll is made.

Comment: I rewrote cup, it works much better now, but still I got two empty lists from Ten and Twenty sided dices when I print out the result, but when roll and sum, they are not empty. Would you pls take a look?

Comment: you have typos in your variable names, ` self.sixSDLst ` `self.tenSDlst `        `self.twentySDlst`  `print(self.sixSDLst,self.tenSDLst,self.twentySDLst)` so when you try to print them it prints the empty lists you have defined at the start of the cup class

Comment: Also you should accept an answer to your original question and create a new question if you still have problems, as the scope changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I corrected them. So far my problems are solved.